# Flask-paginate displaying too many results

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement flask-paginate to return specific number of resuts per page. I followed the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) and it's still displaying all records. I also checked example at [github](https://github.com/lixxu/flask-paginate), but couldn't seen what am I doing wrong. My def in python:

```
def dashboard():
   page_size = 1
   files = File.query.order_by(File.title)
   search = False
   q = request.args.get('q')
   if q:
      search = True
   page = int(request.args.get('page',1))
   pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=files.count(), per_page=page_size, css_framework='bootstrap3', search=search)
   return render_template('dashboard.html', files=files, pagination=pagination)
```

And html template:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block body %}

<table border=2 padding=10>
   <tr padding="10">
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>Filename</td>
   </tr>
{% for file in files %}
  <tr padding=10>
     <td padding=10> {{ file.username }} </td>
     <td padding=10> {{ file.title }} </td>
     <td><a href="{{ url_for('static', filename=file.file) }}">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}

{% endblock %}
```

The outcome:

[image]

So as you can see, pagination.info displays number of records correctly, but it still displays every record, despite variable per_page set as 1.

Comment: You iterate over files instead of pagination.

Comment: You confuse Flask-SQLAlchemy pagination and Flask-Paginate (the last one is used in the given example)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on VKolev's answer, you need an offset variable and to apply per_page and offset to the query. There's actually a handy [built-in](https://github.com/lixxu/flask-paginate/blob/master/example/app.py) to set up page, per_page, and offset all at the same time, which you can import using `from flask_paginate import get_page_args`). In your example, however, since you want different values than the default, it's just as easy to do manually. Here's what the full view.py code would look like:

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_args

@search.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    page = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
    per_page = 1
    offset = (page - 1) * per_page

    files = File.query.order_by(File.title)
    files_for_render = files.limit(per_page).offset(offset)

    search = False

    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True

    pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, offset=offset,
                           total=files.count(), css_framework='bootstrap3', 
                           search=search)

    return render_template('dashboard.html', files=files_for_render, pagination=pagination)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, there is pagination already. Just add `.pagination()` after the `order_by()`. For more info check the [documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination).

Flask-Paginate is only rendering pagination, the actual pagination is done in the select. So you should do limit and offset manually

```
File.query.order_by(File.title).limit(per_page).offset(page*page_size)
```

(this is just an example, no guaranties it will work)